# Python: Returning multiple values from a function into the arguments of another function

Tags: python

is it possible to do something like that?

```
def multireturn():
  return 1, 2, 3

def add(a, b, c):
  return a+b+c

add(multireturn())
```

When I tried it, it errored as it sees only one argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to unpack the `tuple` returned from the first function to make it behave as sequential positional arguments to the second. The `*` unpacking operator allows this:

```
add(*multireturn())
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the unpacking operator `*` to unpack the `tuple` returned from the first function . try :

```
add(*multireturn())
```